# How do I determine where a header redirect came from

Tags: php, session, redirect, header, breadcrumbs

I need to find a way that the target of a header() redirect can determine what page initiated the redirect.  We are using a mod_auth_cas hack to validate logins.  Since we cannot have the entire site behind mod_auth_cas we have a sub-directory with AuthType Cas in the .htaccess.  for logins we give a link to the /cas directory, the cas is processed, the returned userid is added to the $_SESSION and compared to our permissions database, then the page is header redirected to the homepage.

This dance works well when just returning to the homepage but we would like pages that require a login to redirect to the cas when there is no userid in $_SESSION.  And when the user logs in and we get the userid back it redirects back to the page that sent it there, not the homepage.  And this ability to look back at the originating page of a header redirect would be handy in other parts of the site.

How can the /cas/index.php determine what page originated the redirect?  How do I avoid a collision where a user has multiple pages open, is simultaneously is redirected to the cas on one, goes to a second page where they are also redirected to the cas, compeletes the cas goes back to the first one, completes it again and is redirected to the second page not the first one?  And this solution has to be pure PHP, no javascript tracking.

Comment: Why not store the originating url in the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THere are a few ways you can do this.

-Either store the original URL in the session before the redirect

-On the login page, grab the referring url from the $_SERVER variable and redirect to that after login

-Adjust your redirect so it adds the current URL to the get/post variables on the login page
-- noaccess.php gets redirect to login.php?ret_url=noaccess.php (you would probably want to use the full url and url encode it)

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying or adding any code at all you can install the XDebug php extension and turn on profiling. It will spit out a cachegrind file containing info about the callstack. You can open it in something like kcachegrind to get a visual representation of when the call to header() happened.